# Service retrieves data from datastore but does not update ui

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a service which retrieves data from the datastore (Web SQL). Afterwards, it stores the data in a AngularJS array. The problem is that this does not initiate changes to the UI.

Contrary, if after the retrieval of data from datastore, I call a web services using a $get method and append the results to the previous array, all data updates the UI.

Any suggestions? Is it possible that I fill the array before the Angular binds the variable?

Can I somehow delay the execution of the service?

Most of the code has been taken from the following example: http://vojtajina.github.io/WebApp-CodeLab/FinalProject/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the UI to magically update, some changes must happen on properties of the $scope. For example, if retrieving some users from a rest resource, I might do something like this:

```
app.controller("UserCtrl", function($http) {
  $http.get("users").success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data; // update $scope.users IN the callback
  }
)
```

Though there is a better way to retrieve data before a template is loaded (via routes/ng-view):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, userFactory) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/users", {
      templateUrl: "pages/user.html",
      controller: "UserCtrl",
      resolve: {
        // users will be available on UserCtrl (inject it)
        users: userFactory.getUsers() // returns a promise which must be resolved before $routeChangeSuccess
    }
  }
});
app.factory("userFactory", function($http, $q) {
  var factory = {};
  factory.getUsers = function() {
    var delay = $q.defer(); // promise
    $http.get("/users").success(function(data){
      delay.resolve(data); // return an array of users as resolved object (parsed from JSON)
    }).error(function() {
      delay.reject("Unable to fetch users");
    });
    return delay.promise; // route will not succeed unless resolved
  return factory;
});
app.controller("UserCtrl", function($http, users) { // resolved users injected
  // nothing else needed, just use users it in your template - your good to go!
)
```

I have implemented both methods and the latter is far desirable for two reasons:

It doesn't load the page until the resource is resolved. This allows you to place a loading icon, etc, by attaching handlers on the $routeChangeStart and $routeChangeSuccess.

Furthermore, it plays better with 'enter' animations in that, all your items don't annoyingly play the enter animation every time the page is loaded (since $scope.users is pre populated as opposed to being updated in a callback once the page has loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're assigning the data to the `array` in the `controller`, set an `$scope.$apply()` after to have the UI update.

Ex:

```
$scope.portfolio = {};

$scope.getPortfolio = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://website.com:1337/portfolio',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $scope.portfolio = data;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });     

};
```